# How does sudo decide whether to ask for a password, when given a command which doesn't actually need `sudo`?

Tags: sudo, password

When applying `sudo` to a command which doesn't actually need `sudo`,

- sometimes it doesn't ask me for my password. For example under my `$HOME`, `sudo ls`.
- But I remember that it does for some other command, though I forget which one.

So I was wondering how `sudo` decides whether to ask for a password, when given a command which doesn't actually need `sudo`? Is there some rule in `/etc/sudoers` specifying that?

My real problem is that when I use `du`, it sometimes shows "permission denied" for some directories, and sometimes not, probably because I don't have permission on some directories? I apply `sudo` to `du` regardless, and thought I would be asked for a password regardless, but actually not on my own directories.

Comment: Deciding whether a program _would_ attempt to do something that only root can do, or access a file that the invoking user is forbidden to access, without actually running the program, is the Halting Problem in disguise.  So you can be sure that's not what sudo is doing.

Comment: +1 because although the question is based on a misconception, the symptoms are clearly explained, and it has one unambiguous answer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In a typical configuration, the command is irrelevant. You need to enter your password the first time you use sudo, and you don't need your password in that particular shell for the next 15 minutes.

From the computer's perspective, there is no such thing as a “command that needs sudo”. Any user can attempt to run any command. The outcome may be nothing but an error message such as “Permission denied” or “No such file or directory”, but it's always possible to run the command.

For example, if you run `du` on a directory tree that has contents that you don't have permission to access, you'll get permission errors. That's what “permission denied” means. If you run `sudo du`, sudo runs `du` as root, so you don't get permission errors (that's the point of the root account: root¹ always has permission). When you run `sudo du`, `du` runs as root, and `sudo` is not involved at all after `du` has started. Whether du encounters permission errors is completely irrelevant to how sudo operates.

There are commands that need sudo *to do something useful*. Usefulness is a human concept. You need to use sudo (or some other methods to run the command as root) if the command does something useful when run as root but not when run under your account.

Whether sudo asks for your password depends on two things.

1. Based on the configuration, sudo decides whether you need to be authenticated. By default, sudo requires a password. This can be turned off in several ways, including setting the `authenticate` option to false and having an applicable rule with the `NOPASSWD` tag.
2. If sudo requires your password, it may be content to use a cached value. That's ok because the reason sudo needs your password is not to authenticate who's calling it (sudo knows what user invoked it), but to confirm that it's still you at the commands and not somebody who took control over your keyboard. By default, sudo is willing to believe that you're still at the commands if you entered your password less than 15 minutes ago (this can be changed with the `timeout` option). You need to have entered the password in the same terminal (so that if you remain logged in on one terminal then leave that terminal unattended and then use another terminal, someone can't take advantage of this to use sudo on the other terminal — but this is a very weak advantage and it can be turned off by setting the `tty_tickets` option to false).

¹  <sub>nearly, but that's beyond the scope of this thread.</sub>

Comment: There might be files which have the executable bit set just for root, not for others. This might be fall unter "need root to execute". (Just nitpicking.)

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann I wrote “any user _can attempt_ to run any command” to avoid nitpicking about that (rare) case. There's always a nitpicker :(

Answer (score 44):

`sudo` doesn’t know whether the command it’s asked to run needs to run as some other user (typically root), all it knows is its configuration. That determines which users are allowed to run `sudo`, with what users as “targets”, and for what commands; it also determines whether a password is needed, which one, and whether to keep an authentication token around.

If you’re using the default Debian configuration, the latter is most likely what’s involved here: `sudo` will ask you for your password the first time you use it in any given terminal, then it will keep an authentication token for a certain amount of time. If you re-use `sudo` in the same terminal within that timeframe, it won’t prompt you for a password.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean `sudo du /path/to/some/dir` should either always need my password, or never, regardless of `/path/to/some/dir`?

Comment: Yes. It will always need your password (or not). Clearly, if it needs your password but has already stored it in the cache, it won't prompt you to enter it.

Comment: Strictly speaking it *could* depend on the path, because `/etc/sudoers` can specify commands and their arguments. However if you haven’t added anything like that to `sudoers` (and if you have, I should hope you’d be aware of it), the arguments won’t matter (nor will the command if you have general access to root *via* `sudo`).

Comment: `sudo` does not store your password in the cache, only the information that your identity has already been verified once with a password check. Since `sudo` is a setuid-root program, it already has all the permissions it needs to run anything as anyone - but it is trusted to only allow the users to use it exactly as specified in the `sudoers` file, and to reject all other attempts to use it. That's why it is important that `sudo` is such a small and very well studied program.

Answer (score 6):

> to a command which doesn't actually need sudo

It's not that a command *needs* or *needs not* sudo. When you run

```
sudo -u user command
```

the system executes `command` as the `user`.

Whether the invocation is successful or not, and whether a password is asked or not, depends on the security policy `sudoers` (usually configured in `/etc/sudoers`).